# Windows Recycle Bin information file binary format

Tags: windows, binaryfiles, explorer, recycle-bin

Programmatic removing of files to Recycle Bin in Windows is a trivial operation.

In short: just move a file to
`C:\$Recycle.Bin\SID\$R{name}`* *(for drive C)*  and create an associated binary file (`$I{name}`) with meta information about the "deleted" file/folder near it.

** where [SID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier) is your OS installation identifier that looks like: `S-1-5-21-1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-1001`.*

---

But I have two question after researching:

- **What is the algorithm of encoding the deletion date to 64-bit value?**
- Are the file names (in a trash bin) random generated or there is some logic?

---

The information file structure is follow (based on my research):

```js
const buffer = new Uint8Array([
    0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Header
    0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Size                // 65535 (bytes)
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0xd7, 0x01,  // Deletion date (64-bit value)
    0x0b, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,                          // Path string length  // `11`
                            0x43, 0x00, 0x3a, 0x00,  // File path + \0      // `C:\1\1.txt`  // `C:\\1\\1.txt\0`
    0x5c, 0x00, 0x31, 0x00, 0x5c, 0x00, 0x31, 0x00,
    0x2e, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00, 0x78, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00
]);
```

Header (always is the same), file size in bytes *(which is only visible in File Explorer)*, 64-bit deletion date value, path string length, and UTF-16 encoded null-terminated path string.

The only questionable part is the date. **How is it encoded?**

For example:

`00 00 00 00 00 29 d7 01` is 2021.04.04 03:10

`00 00 00 00 01 29 d7 01` is 2021.04.04 03:17

`00 00 00 00 00 30 d7 01` is 2021.04.13 00:57

*(The first four hexes is `00` just for convenience.)*

For example: `00 00 00 00 00 29 d7 01` is `132619794007457792`, but `new Date(132619794007457792/100000)` is `2012.01.10 12:19:00`.

I need to transform `00 00 00 00 00 29 d7 01` bytes to `2021.04.04 03:10`.

---

The "deleted" files in `C:\$Recycle.Bin\SID\` have name that is started with `$R` + `[A-Z0-9]{7}` + optional `.{extension}`.
For example: `$RL6JQMF.txt`.
And associated meta data file: `$IL6JQMF.txt` that just starts with `$I`.

Is there some logic for the naming or it is just a random generated one?

In fact, for example, it works well with both `$R___` + `$I___`, and with `$R123456789 abc` + `$I123456789 abc`. So, I think it is just random generated.

Only the `$R`/`$I` is required. The extension is needed only just to shows the corresponding icon in the File Explorer.

Comment: One con of this approach is what the recycle bin state will not change until you refresh the recycle bin. So, if you move a file to an _empty_ recycle bin, the icon of it will not change, even the file is already showed in File Explorer.

Comment: note that the "header" on Windows 7/8.1 starts with `0x01`, and the structure doesn't have the field for path length

Comment: Here is a documentation for all Recycle Bin formats since Win95 beta : https://github.com/danielmarschall/recyclebinunit/blob/master/FORMAT.md . Also, at this repo there is a Delphi library and ready compiled EXE file to read recycle bin information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I got it.

While
`00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` is `1899.12.30 00:00`,

but `00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00` is `1601.11.22 18:44`,

so this timestamp is a number of 100-nanosecond intervals since 1601.01.01.

For example, for `00 00 00 00 00 29 d7 01` (`132619794007457792`) I get the correct date (`2021.04.04 03:10`) as it shows in File Explorer with:

```js
new Date(132619794007457792 / 10000 + Number(new Date("1601.01.01 Z")))
```

---

Anyway, I think this topic would be useful for people.

*It's strange that in 2021 I did not found any info about how Recycle Bin in Windows works.*

Comment: Isn't it just [FILETIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime) ?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it is. Fixed.

Comment: Why don't you just use Windows API to send files to recycle bin?

Comment: I have no experience with win-api, c++, and how to use it in node.js app. Knowledge of the information file structure allows you to do everything in very common way: read, delete, restore files and more: customise deletion date and displayed size.

Answer (score 3):

Ive done some extensive research on this, as it seems, surprisingly, there is very few info available online on how Recycle Bin actually implemented.

Everything is not that hard to grasp. When you delete file in the Bin, it is not actually moved to it.

First, lets take a look at the subfolders of `$Recycle.Bin`:

- `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18` is folder for built-in SYSTEM account
- `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-1XXX\`, starting from 1000 are non-built in user folders. You should first check which one of them is the one you need by typing `whoami /all` in command prompt to get your SID, or `wmic useraccount get name,sid` to get all local accounts SIDs, then choose the folder matching with SID.

If you give security rights to your account to all this folders, Explorer might show your deleted files in every folder, however its just Explorer bug. If you navigate to, say, `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18` folder and type `dir /a`, you will see that its actually empty, and only folder that match with your SID contains your deleted files.

Note that even if you are the only user on the PC, you might still have folder `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-1000\` that most likely will be empty. Then your actual folder will be `...-1001\`. User "1000" seems to be dangling folder for user that was created automatically by Windows on installation or some updates, then deleted. But `Recycle.Bin` folder wasn't destroyed and just stayed there. I assume that its safe to delete this dangling folder. I'm not so sure about `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18`, but I'm fairly sure its safe too, as there is no need for OS SYSTEM account to use the Bin, anyway.

So, here is deletion algorithm:

1. System creates [hardlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions) of the deleted file in `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-1XXX\` folder with the name `$RXXXXXX.<file_ext>`, where `XXXXXX` is 6 symbols HASH calculated based on the file contents, as I assume.
2. Metadata file is created in the same folder with the name `$IXXXXXX.<file_ext>`. I will show you the content of this file later.
3. Original file is deleted, but because of extra hardlink in `$Recycle.Bin`, actual file's data stays in the same location on the drive as if file where never touched. It is not moved anywhere. This is why each logical volume must have it's own `$Recycle.Bin` folder, as hardlinks only work within the same volume.

That's about it. Restoration algorithm:

1. Metadata file is read and hardlink of `$RXXXXXX.<file_ext>` is created based on `$IXXXXXX.<file_ext>`'s info in original file location, with original file name.
2. Both metadata and backup file are deleted from `$Recycle.Bin`

Pretty simple, ain't it?

Now, the most interesting part is that metadata file:

```
0000  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  <-- File header (QW)
0008  00 7C 0A 00 00 00 00 00  <-- File size (QW)
0010  90 83 72 44 28 9C D8 01  <-- File deletion date (QW)
0018  18 00 00 00|43 00 3A 00  <-- File path string length (DW)
0020  5C 00 24 00 52 00 65 00  
0028  63 00 79 00 63 00 6C 00
0030  65 00 2E 00 42 00 69 00
0038  6E 00 5C 00 66 00 73 00
0040  73 00 2E 00 65 00 78 00
0048  65 00 00 00|             <-- |Null-terminated path string| (wchar_t)
```

All values are in [Little Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) format.

Header is fixed and its identical for all the files. Be warned that some `$I` files might have some junk bytes `FF FE` appear before the Header. I have no idea what are this for, so you should check for full header before reading further.

Deletion date is in [FILETIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime) format and can be converted to usual [SYSTEMTIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-systemtime) via [FileTimeToSystemTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-filetimetosystemtime). It represents 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

So it's not super complicated file format, but quite interesting design.

I'm planing to use this info myself by creating custom "garbage collector" for Windows, that I will add to task scheduler to launch periodically and scan\delete files that where deleted more than 24 hours ago, etc. I know that Windows 10 has built-in option for this, but it's not flexible and not reliable (it sometimes leaves metadata files, while only deleteing `$R` files). Also, I think, previous Windows versions doesn't have this feature at all.

I encourage you to experiment with this too! For example, your program might save metadata info of all files it removes into some database, so you would have full history of all files you ever deleted!

Comment: Here is [sample output](https://i.imgur.com/ZUPEFBb.png) from my program's prototype.

Comment: Neither Fat32 nor Win95 had hardlinks so I assume it moves the file.

Comment: Hey, since SO doesn't let me edit the answer. The "junk bytes" seem to be little endian BOM.

Comment: Another interesting observation, is that the metadata files are actually kept when restoring files via explorer. I am puzzled as to why they are doing this. FYI, I am on Windows 11.