# recycle bin $I file header 0xff

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

I was curious about the $I file while creating the 'Recycle Bin' viewer for a university project.

I understand that the first four digits of the $I file represent operating system information.

When I looked up my file, almost all the files were 0x02.

However, the header of one file is 0xff.
What does this 0xff mean?

And if possible, I would also like to know the appropriate operating system list for the information in each header.

I apologize for my poor English.

I use window 11

in python

```
with open('C:/$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-21-....-XXXX/$I24JSBG.pdf', mode='rb') as file:
    binaryData = file.read()

print(binaryData[28:].decode(encoding='utf-16', errors='strict')[:-1])
```

The other file outputs '02 00 00 00', but for this file outputs 'ff 00 00 00'.

Comment: The formatting has nothing to do with Python, but has everything to do with how the "Recycling Bin" tracks content.  Related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66939004/windows-recycle-bin-information-file-binary-format).

Comment: Thanks to this, I can know find 'FF FE' appearing in $I files sometimes.
I already know that 'FF FE' mark Little Endian.
but, my $I file header is 'FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'.

I'm confused because it's neither "FF FE" nor "02".